# Jquery to store Tempdata

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I need my jquery func to store in tempdata which i can use when user moves to another controller.
Something like

```
$(function () {TempData["OrderID"] = e.row.OrderID;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use `TempData` here as it only persists to the next request and when setting it asynchronously, you can't control when that next request will be. If some other bit of AJAX happens to run before the user moves on, then you've already burned your "next request". You should either use `Session` or persist in some other way (local storage or an actual database perhaps).

Second, you can't run server-side code, once you're client-side (where JavaScript runs), as a result, your only option is to use AJAX to send a request to a controller action that then responds by setting some bit of information in the session. Also, be aware that when you do this you *must* use an MVC controller action, not a Web Api action. Web Api is stateless and has no access to the session, even if the Web Api controllers are in the same project as your MVC site.